# Overflow in casting in C

Tags: c, casting, overflow

```
char c = 250;
c += 8;
```

What value does `c` have after the above statements are executed?

I am unable to decode the procedure to solve this question, also hint is to use binary addition.

Comment: Assuming `c` is signed, the overflow is undefined according to the C standard. In many implementations, setting `c` to 250 will overflow to -6, then adding 8 will make `c` 2. This is implementation dependant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still I would like to ask that is there any possible way to solve this using binary addition?

Comment: The hint to use binary addition is that 250 is 11111010 in binary, and 8 is 1000, and their sum is 100000010, which is nine bits. If a `char` holds only the last eight bits, the first 1 is lost, and the value is 00000010, so the result is 2. However, this hint ignores the rules of C. If `char` is unsigned, this binary view of the arithmetic is okay; C’s modulo-wrapping rules are equivalent to discarding high bits. If `char` is signed, the rules of C may differ from this binary view; an implementation is allowed to do things other than use the low eight bits.

Comment: Note the is no _casting_ done nor _overflow_ here.  There is _assignment_.

Answer (score 4):

## Introduction

There are two practical cases to consider:

- `char` is unsigned and eight bits. For this, the result is 2.
- `char` is signed and eight bits. For this, the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

## The char type is unsigned and eight bits

In this case, `char c = 250;` is straightforward; it initializes `c` to 250. Then, in `c += 8;`, the statement is equivalent to `c = c + 8;`. In this statement, `c` is promoted to `int`, and the addition is performed, resulting in 258. Finally, this result must be converted to `char` to be stored in `c`.

The rule for converting to an unsigned type is to adjust the value modulo “one more than the maximum value” that can be represented. That is, for an unsigned `char` where the maximum value is 255, we add or subtract 256 to make a representable value. So 258 becomes 258−256 = 2, and `c` is set to 2.

## The char type is signed and eight bits

In this case, `char c = 250;` attempts to initialize `c` with a value that it cannot represent. Per C 2018 6.7.9 11, the initialization is performed like an assignment. Per 6.5.16.1 2, assignment converts the value to the type of the left operand (after lvalue conversion). Per 6.3.1.3 3, conversion of a value that cannot be represented to a signed type is implementation defined:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Assuming execution continues past `char c = 250;` to `c += 8;`, then 8 is added to whatever value `c` was initialized to. This cannot overflow since the operands are promoted to the `int` type, and any `char` value plus 8 is representable in `int`. If the result of the addition is representable in `char`, it is stored in `c`. Otherwise, the rules for conversion apply again: The result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

## Hypothetical situations

These situations rarely or never occur in modern practice.

If `char` is signed and nine bits, then 250 is representable, so `c` is initialized to 250. Then, in `c += 8;`, the addition produces a result that is not representable in `char` (the maximum would be 255), so the conversion rules discussed above apply, and the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined result is raised.

If `char` is wider than nine bits, no errors occur, and `c` ends up being 258.

If `char` were the same width as `int` (a hypothetical possibility discussed elsewhere on Stack Overflow), and `char c = 250;` were changed to, say, `char c = INT_MAX-5;`, then `c` would be initialized without problem, but `c += 8;` would overflow during the arithmetic, and then the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: and all others:I thank once again to all. Now I'm clear with it, it's fixed. May this New Year bring happiness to all!! Amen

Answer (score 2):

If the `char` is 8-bit `unsigned` the result is `2` which is `258 % 256`.

If the char is `signed` the result is <strike>undefined</strike> implementation defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot Weather Vane!! Further it is obvious that % is taking remainder value(if I'm not wrong). So is there any possible way to solve using binary addition. Also why is result undefined if char is signed? Hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: @Nikhil the binary addition is `1111 1010 + 0000 1000 = 1 0000 0010` and the modulus, which can be seen as a truncation to 8 bits, leaves `0000 0010` which is decimal `2`.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil:Sir, could you please let me know the difference between arithmetic overflow rules & conversion rules.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.3 Conversions 6.3.1 Arithmetic operands 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.* Note: **implementation defined**

Comment: @Kikky: The rules in clause 6.3 of the C standard (2018 and 2011 versions) govern conversions, which are what occur when a value is changed from one type to another type. Such conversions occur automatically in assignments, initializations, function call arguments, and some other places. Arithmetic overflow is what occurs when the mathematical result of an arithmetic operation is not representable in the type being used for arithmetic. Differ rules apply; the mathematical result is not automatically converted to the necessary type.

Comment: @Weather Van:Thanks a lot, Wish you all a very Happy New Year 2019!!